# Include client multi part form file in new POST request

Tags: go, multipartform-data

Think I might be missing something obvious here. I'm attempting to grab the file from a client request hitting my server and forwarding that to an external API for processing by creating a new multipart request and copying the file over. In this case, the API is looking for a FormFile under the "files" key. The receiving API keeps telling me the file `has invalid mime type application/octet-stream`

[API Call Documentation](https://docs.butlerlabs.ai/reference/upload-documents-queues)

```
func forwardFile(r *http.Request) (string, error) {
    file, fileHandler, err := r.FormFile("image")
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)

    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("files", fileHandler.Filename)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    if _, err := io.Copy(part, file); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    writer.Close()

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", newUploadUrl, body)
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
    client := &http.Client{}
    response, err := client.Do(req)
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: *"The receiving API keeps telling me ..."* - This means that the API is not expecting what you send. It is unknown though what the receiving API is actually expecting. Please provide the relevant information in your question or link to the API documentation. Also, it is unclear what the error message actually refers too - the content-type of the POST body (which you set as FormData) or the content-type of the file upload (which you don't set):

Comment: Thanks the quick response, I added the documentation! I also tried adding using CreateFormField to add the type but it didn’t seem like it affected the response.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to change your content type to `multipart/form-data`

Comment: I believe that’s covered by writer.FormDataContentType() which also includes the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by creating a MIMEHeader and populating the disposition and content type myself, see below:

```
partHeader := textproto.MIMEHeader{}
disposition := fmt.Sprintf("form-data; name=\"files\"; filename=\"%s\"", fileHandler.Filename)
partHeader.Add("Content-Disposition", disposition)
partHeader.Add("Content-Type", "image/png")
part, err := writer.CreatePart(partHeader)

if _, err := io.Copy(part, file); err != nil {
  log.Print("Error copying")
  return "", err
}
```